# MSBuild Task and Roslyn

Tags: msbuild, task, roslyn

We have written our own MSBuild Task and want to use Roslyn within this task.
We are referencing

- Microsoft.Build
- Microsoft.Build.Engine
- Microsoft.Build.Framework
- Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core
- Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core

each with version v14.0 to be as low as possible.
If we now install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis via Nuget (We tried Latest 2.8.2, or even 1.3.2), and are using a Type, we get a ReflectionTypeLoadException with an inner loaderexception of type FileNotFoundException ("System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

I assume this is because the msbuild.exe is running within the msbuild path, and is not probing our path for the dependencies, but the question would be how we should solve this situation?

Thanks for any hint!